# Text over an image on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using Wordpress to build a website and have used an image as the background of my home page but want to add text over the top which also links to another page on my site. Do I need to amend the coding or can this simply be done when editing the page on visual mode? If I need to amend the coding can someone please help??

Answer (score 2):

This is the idea how the text should look over an image. You can easily manipulate the text using CSS.

[image: Schematics]
**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
      <img src="images/3754004820_91a5c238a0.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

**Final result:**
[image: result]

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/